# Multilingual + iso

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

The problem one is facing is that Drupal 7/8 does not seem to be able to determine a country from the locale i.e. the language. One needs to write custom code to link the country to a language. Or are there custom modules for that?

Why does Drupal don't use ISO language code and country code conventions for its language package? e.g. the ISO 639-1 language code, an underscore (_), then the ISO 3166-1 alpha-2 country code (e.g. fr_FR for French/France).

E.g. [language ISO 639-1]_[country ISO 3166-1] e.g. it_IT, it_CH, it_SM, etc. For Belgium e.g. there are 3 languages: nl_BE, fr_BE, de_BE. Couldn't be cleaner to my opinion. You could even make nuance differences between your languages assuming Italian in CH could differ from IT in Italy. Please also refer to symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html

One would then have the advantage of knowing to which country a language belongs. I don't understand the reasoning of Drupal to just use the language code. It seems countries should be handled somewhere else but logically a language always belongs to a country.

W

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You cannot determine the country from the language. For example, [Italian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Italian_language) is the official language not just in Italy, but also Switzerland, San Marino, Vatican City, and Sovereign Military Order of Malta. You cannot assume Italian => Italy, and the same is for other languages too. How would you do for those countries where the official languages are more than one?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but I don't really agree with your remark. [language ISO code]_[country ISO code] can perfectly do the job. e.g. it_IT, it_CH, it_SM, etc. For Belgium e.g. there are 3 languages: nl_BE, fr_BE, de_BE. Couldn't be cleaner to my opinion. You could even make nuance differences between your languages assuming Italian in CH could differ from IT in Italy. Please also refer to http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html -> this actually makes sense to me.

Comment: My browser sends *en_US* as _Accept-Language_ header, which just means I prefer pages in American English. What would you understand about the country from a header like `Accept-Language: da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7`?

Comment: Also, notice that neither *fr_BE* nor *de_BE* is [sent from a browser](http://www.metamodpro.com/browser-language-codes).

Comment: Although this may be a problem, that's not really my question. My question is more about Drupal being able to make a relationship between language and a country. I don't currently see how you would attach a language like Italian to three different countries in Drupal without having to write custom code. So far I can see there is one Italian language and there is no way to link it to different countries. A use case would be e.g. you have a Country Editor for Italy and he would be able to login and see content only of it_IT. Maybe I'm missing something :-) Thanks for your reply though.

Comment: It cannot make any relation because there isn't any relation between spoken language and country. As for Swiss Italian, that is different from the Italian spoken in Italy; in fact, _driving license_ is _permesso di condurre_ in Swiss Italian, but _patente di guida_ in Italian. If somebody would tell me _permesso di condurre_, I would take he doesn't speak Italian very fluently, but a Swiss would find that perfectly normal.

Comment: Exactly, and this comes back to my question. Why Drupal does not introduce such a thing like it_IT locale, it_CH locale, etc. We know only have 'it' which like your example show does not make sense to me because some countries have other translations for that language. My question is just about 'naming' your local package according to ISO standards with [ISO langauge]_[ISO country]. There is no reason why there shouldn't be a relation between language and country in the Drupal *backend*.

Comment: I wanted something like this for Custom Content translations. like we have locales being sent up by mobile devices to our api defined in Drupal8... it would be nice if i can serve the fr_CA version of node/101 content pretend, instead of fr_FR. Having Locale Translations makes sense in the Content area, would be nice to 'opt-in' full locale translations there (vs adding regional language translations for Drupals GUI Interface).